# whats the difference between _kbhit and kbhit in C?

Tags: c, conio

I know `kbhit` "Determines if a keyboard key was pressed" but I see that people use both `_kbhit` and `kbhit` interchangeably.

Comment: `conio.h` is pretty obsolete. You should switch to something like `ncurses`

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/posix-kbhit?view=msvc-160

Comment: `conio.h` is very obsolete and the functions are 100% non-portable to anything but windows. The curses library should be used if any type of portability is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this page on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/posix-kbhit?view=msvc-160) - `kbhit` is deprecated

> The Microsoft-specific function name kbhit is a deprecated alias for the _kbhit function. By default, it generates Compiler warning (level 3) C4996. The name is deprecated because it doesn't follow the Standard C rules for implementation-specific names. However, the function is still supported.

> We recommend you use _kbhit instead. Or, you can continue to use this function name, and disable the warning. For more information, see Turn off the warning and POSIX function names.